# sed syntax, error unmatched ( or \(

Tags: regex, sed, cmake

Trying to comment out "cmake_policy(SET CMP0022" in a cmake file with a # using sed from another cmake file. Tried escaping ( and space, but am not doing it right somehow. What's the right syntax?

```
set(PATCH_CMP0022 "s/cmake_policy\\(SET\\ CMP0022/#cmake_policy(SET\\ CMP0022/")
sed ${PATCH_CMP0022} ${PATCH_FILE} -i
```

If it matters, here's my entire cmake code block...

```
if(NOT EXISTS ${NAME}-patch)
    message("--- Patching ${NAME} ---")
    set(PATCH_CMP0022 "s/cmake_policy\\(SET\\ CMP0022/#cmake_policy(SET\\ CMP0022/")
    message(${PATCH_CMP0022})
    set(PATCH_SOURCE_DIR "s/CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR/CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR/")
    set(PATCH_FILE "${NAME}-src/CMakeLists.txt")
    execute_process(
        COMMAND sed ${PATCH_CMP0022} ${PATCH_FILE} -i
        COMMAND sed ${PATCH_SOURCE_DIR} ${PATCH_FILE} -i
        COMMAND touch ${NAME}-patch
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PATH_LIB})
endif()
```

Comment: Without `-r` option [sed uses \\(\\) for grouping](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64195/how-to-replace-a-left-parenthesis-with-sed). So you needn't to escape anything in your sed command: `set(PATCH_CMP0022 "s/cmake_policy(SET CMP0022/#cmake_policy(SET CMP0022/")`. Also, it is better to enclose into double quotes a reference to that variable - `"${PATCH_CMP0022}"` - so CMake won't treat semicolon specially (for the case when semicolon will be used).

Answer (score 1):

if your data in 'd' file, try gnu sed at most 3 () pairs check,

```
 sed -E 's/.*\([^\)]+[^\)]*$|.*(\(.*){2}\)[^\)]*$|.*(\(.*){3}\)\)[^\)]*$/#&/'
```